# How to prevent space in output due to line break in the HTML code?

Tags: html, jinja2

I have seen this question up here and some are solving it by comment tags or breaking tags like this:

```
 <i><!--
-->t does not work on the first level with tabspace = 2
   beside it looks horrible.  
<a
 >nnoying<
/a> is it not?
```

I remember as if I have seen some trick like

```
<a>&dont_put_here_space_please;
  tricky ampersand code.
```

Is there any such thing?

I am using now **jinja2** python template engine. Does it have some space-preventing trick?

**UPDATE:**

With jinja2, thanks to dav1d, the shortest way I could come up with is:

```
<a>{% if true -%}
  No space in the output before this text.
</a>{% endif -%}
  Nor after.
```

Is there any shorter way of doing this?

Comment: Are you thinking of &nbsp; ?

Comment: @remyabel: the opposite of it :) something like &nosp;

Comment: You have seen [this](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#whitespace-control)?

Comment: @dav1d Oh, cool! Can you please put it into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Sure, added it as answer

Answer (score 15):

Jinja2 WhiteSpace Control is what you need (according to your reponse to my comment): http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#whitespace-control

Comment: Not yet... can you please show me how you would do it? I've tried `<a>{% -%}` but that is not allowed it says. :(

Comment: Uh, sorry can't help you with that one, it's a while I used Jinja myself.

Answer (score 9):

This should do what you want:

```
{# -#}
```

Comment: This one is the shortest one. I suppose it is better than playing with `if true`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I'd like to share how I got it to work around in my code: Using span.

```
<span> .../line1... /line2 ... </span>
```